# How to run "npx create-vite" from a child process in node?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am trying find a way to generate templates from Vite using `exec` from `child_process`
[Current program I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkC1O.png)

I am unable to see any output. Is there something I can do? [There is no Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BVyD.png)

The cmd is running.[Node is taking up processor resources as it runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkEF9.png)

I am very new to CLI Applications. I can't really understand where to even look for a problem as there are no error messages nor a point of clear direction to solve this.